# Find specific group of words in a string list

Tags: python, string, list

Let's say I have a list of strings, generated from a text:

```
string_lst = ['A', 'cat', 'is', 'a', 'cat', 'but', 'a', 'dog', 'is', 'not', 'a', 'cat']
```

( The condition is to keep the string list separated as is. )

Imagine that the strings have the following assignments:

```
A | WORD

cat | ANIMAL

is | WORD

a | WORD

cat | ANIMAL

but | WORD

a | WORD

dog | ANIMAL

is | WORD

not | WORD

a | WORD

cat | ANIMAL
```

I need you to find only the strings, in their natural sequence, ( ANIMAL + WORD + WORD + ANIMAL ), that is, give me a group of words in that exact sequence.
Using the example above, the result will be: 'cat is a cat', 'cat but a dog'

Any idea?

Comment: Did you forget to post the code you're having trouble with?

Comment: Welcome to SO. As this it looks like a homework or assignment with no tentative showed. Please read [ask] and [mcve] and update your post in order to meet the Stack standard. Mainly you should answer the following questions: What have you tried so far? and What problem are you facing?

Comment: Hello JCaesar. I actually had the concept but I couldn't develop the code. Emil105 was able to help me a lot!!! Thanks to the community. I already have the code, understanding to improve on Python. I hope one day to be Emil105 to help colleagues.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You just need a list of all animals

```
string_lst = ['A', 'cat', 'is', 'a', 'cat', 'but', 'a', 'dog', 'is', 'not', 'a', 'cat']

animals = ['dog', 'cat']
result = []
for i in range(len(string_lst) - 4):
    if string_lst[i] in animals and string_lst[i + 1] not in animals and string_lst[i + 2] not in animals and string_lst[i + 3] in animals:
        result.append(string_lst[i:i + 4])

print(result)
```

Comment: Emil105, thank you very much for your help. I usually always look it up on google, on the Python page, and I manage to resolve the impasses that appear...it was the first time I've posted here in the community. My problem was which concept to use to apply, and with your answer it certainly broadens my knowledge, as I'm going to go deeper, not just copy and paste. Again, thank you very much. I gave the positive vote but it didn't show up, because I'm new here I believe....Happy 2022 for you.